# Why is there a discrepancy between the regular x-axis and the x2-axis in gnuplot time data plots?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

So I noticed something I can't quite explain. If I have time values on both x-axis and x2-axis in gnuplot, the same datapoints don't line up. Let me elaborate with a minimal working example.

I have two data files:

One with the actual data:

```
# time1.dat - Some data:
1516205221  1
1516295221  2   "lbl1"
1516626421  3   "lbl2"
1518193566  4   "lbl3"
1518433621  5   "lbl4"
1518539166  6
1518599166  7
```

And one with labels for some datapoints:

```
# Some labels
1516295221  "label1"
1516626421  "label2"
1518193566  "label3"
1518433621  "label4"
```

The first column in each file is the time in unix epoch format (a.k.a. seconds since Jan 1 1970, 00:00:00). Notice how some lines have the same epoch in both files, e.g. the line

```
1516295221  2   "lbl1"
```

in `time1.dat` has the same epoch as the line labeled `"label 1"` in `time2.dat`.

Now if I run

```
reset
set xdata time
set x2data time
set timefmt "%s" # epoch
set x2tics

set tics nomirror front; set yrange [0:]

plot \
    'time1.dat' using ($1):($2):($3) with labels offset 0, char 1 notitle, \
    'time1.dat' using ($1):($2) with points notitle, \
    'time2.dat' using ($1):(NaN):x2tic(2) notitle
```

I get the mismatch seen in the image below. The datapoint "lbl1" should align with the xtic "label1" (and same for "label2"). But they do not. Why is that and how do I fix this problem?

[image: mismatch between two gnuplot time axis]

I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior and I'm just missing a setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` and `x2` axes are completely unrelated. They have their own range, scale and direction. Use `set link` to force a fixed relation between these axes.

In your case simply use `set link x2` to have `x2` be equivalent to `x`:

```
reset
set xdata time
set x2data time
set timefmt "%s" # epoch
set x2tics

set tics nomirror front; set yrange [0:]
set link x2
plot \
    'time1.dat' using ($1):($2):($3) with labels offset 0, char 1 notitle, \
    'time1.dat' using ($1):($2) with points notitle, \
    'time2.dat' using ($1):(NaN):x2tic(2) notitle
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that:

```
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale x2fix
```

are necessary for both `x` and `x2` axes to be aligned.

Not sure why, but it is a fix. However, it has all the other problems that come with auto-scaling. I'm still open for a solution that preserves the range and scaling already in place.

Comment: You could use `set xrange[:]` and `set x2range[:]` in combination with `xfix` and `x2fix`. It is also possible to set a dynamic `xrange` for a given file using the `stats` command.